# Error while installing Catalyst 13.1 on Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit

Tags: drivers, 13.10, ati, dpkg, fglrx

I have Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV730

Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU P7350 @ 2.00GHz × 2

Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV730/M96 [Mobility [Radeon HD 4650](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsAti)/5165]

I downloaded the [AMD Catalyst™ 13.1 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86_64)

i unpacked it and then made these

```
XXX@XXX:~/Downloads$ sudo sh amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/saucy
Created directory fglrx-install.lW2suh
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver-8.97.100.7....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
=====================================================================
AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager 
=====================================================================
Generating package: Ubuntu/saucy
Package /XXX/XXX/XXX/fglrx_8.970-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb has been successfully generated
Package /XXX/XXX/XXX/fglrx-dev_8.970-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb has been successfully generated
Package /XXX/XXX/XXX/fglrx-amdcccle_8.970-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb has been successfully generated
Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.lW2suh
```

I get an error when I install the package

```
XXX@XXX:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx.
(Reading database ... 194458 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fglrx (from fglrx_8.970-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-amdcccle.
Unpacking fglrx-amdcccle (from fglrx-amdcccle_8.970-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-dev.
Unpacking fglrx-dev (from fglrx-dev_8.970-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up fglrx (2:8.970-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl32.icd because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl32.icd (of link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Loading new fglrx-8.970 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.11.0-17-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.11.0-17-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.11.0-17-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.970/build/make.log for more information.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Setting up fglrx-amdcccle (2:8.970-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up fglrx-dev (2:8.970-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-17-generic
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
```

make.log contains

```
DKMS make.log for fglrx-8.970 for kernel 3.11.0-17-generic (x86_64)
Mon Mar  3 19:49:08 CST 2014
AMD kernel module generator version 2.1
kernel includes at /lib/modules/3.11.0-17-generic/build/include not found or incomplete
file: /lib/modules/3.11.0-17-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
```

I'm following this guide: BinaryDriverHowto/AMD and I'm stuck

I am completely at a loss here. I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

For me it works just fine when i install these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress
```

This installs the AMD Catalyst Control Center and i can use my AMD Radeon HD 7600M GPU

Comment: This doesn't work because OP asks for Legacy version of the driver. The package provided by Ubuntu only works for newer cards (including your HD 7600M).